# Best graphing program for Mac or PC?

Tags: graphing-functions, big-list, computational-mathematics, computer-algebra-systems

I just bought the highest end iMac, with a student discount, of course, and was wondering what is the best graphing program out there. A program that can graph any equation that I throw at it AND one where I can manipulate variables such as the window resolution...the same way you do on a Texas Instruments graphing calculator...

Comment: You might want to look into [*Computer Algebra Systems*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer_algebra_systems) There are some excellent CAS programs out there and they do a lot of things and include open source to professional. Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are on a Mac you already have a decent graphing program called Grapher installed. If it isn't already installed then you should certainly be able to find it under a folder on your installation disk.

I've used Grapher to produce nice looking graphs for many math projects and I was very happy with it. Since it already comes free with a Mac, you might as well try it.